# How to defer unused CSS and avoid an excessive DOM size in magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, pagespeed

How to defer unused CSS and avoid an excessive DOM size? Any one knows how to defer unused css and avoid dom size in magento1.9 using pagespeed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hii did you get solution for this?